# D365 Modal Dialog - Close via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm using **Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo** to display a web resource in a modal dialog on the Unified Interface (D365 online v9.1).

Opening the form works perfectly - however i can't see a way to close the dialog from within the web resource once it has been opened.  Is there a supported way to automatically close a modal dialog on the UI?

The code snippit below is opening a webresource in a modal window:

```
let pageInput: Xrm.PageInput = {
    pageType: crm_constants.PageType.webresource,
    webresourceName: "new_/dialogs/dialog.html",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
};

let navigationOptions: Xrm.NavigationOptions = {
    target: 2,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    position: 1
};

Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(pageInput, navigationOptions)
```

**Update:**
I can achieve the desired result by doing this; but would like a more elegant solution.

```
$("button[data-id='dialogCloseIconButton']", parent.document).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use simple window.close(); from the context of your Html webresource. Works for me like a charm.
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no supported way.

Source: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/791

Answer (score 0):

```
$modal=$(parent.window.document).find('section[id$="popupContainer"]');
    
$modal.remove()
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.